# Memory Leak Downloading image from server

Tags: ios, image, memory, memory-leaks

I have a paged slider view with an image on each page. I'm using `NSOperationQueue` to help me download the images from the server while the program is running. The `NSOperationQueue` is used to call the following method,

```
-(NSData *)imageWith:(NSString *)imageName
{

NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

if (!imageData) {

   imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", picsURL,imageName] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];

    if (imageData) {

        [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    }
}     
 return imageData;
}
```

and then I use the main thread to display the downloaded image on the scrollerview:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadPic:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self imageWith:[picsNames objectAtIndex:imageView.tag]], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", imageView.tag], nil] waitUntilDone:YES];
```

which calls the following method:

```
-(void)loadPic:(NSArray *)imageAndTagArray
{
    if (imageAndTagArray.count) {

    //loading the image to imageview
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[scrollView viewWithTag:[[imageAndTagArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:((NSData *)[imageAndTagArray objectAtIndex:0])];

    //stopping the indicator
    [((UIActivityIndicatorView *)[imageView viewWithTag:ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_TAG]) stopAnimating];
}
}
```

Everything works fine for the first 60 images, but after that I receive a Memory Warning and after about 100 images the app crashes.

I have been spending so much time on this and I can't figure out what to do. I've used Instruments and it doesn't detect any leak. I've also used Analyze and that did show anything either.

EDIT:

If I replace the imageWith: method definition with the following definition I still get the warnings, where 5.jpg is a local image.

```
-(NSData *)imageWith:(NSString *)imageName
{
     return UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"5.jpg"]);
}
```

Let me tell you more about the situation.

When the app starts I have a view with a paged scrollview inside it that contains 9 images per page. the scrollview uses the nsoperationqueue to load images which calls the imageWith: method.

when the user taps on any of the images a second view opens with a full display of the selected image. this second view also has a scroll view that contains the same images as the first view but with full display, meaning 1 image per page.

when you are on the second view and scrolling back and forth the app crashes after loading about 60 images.
It also crashes if say it loads 50 images and then you tap on the back button and go to the first view and then tap on another image and go to the second view and load about 10 images.

Comment: Are you using Automatic Reference Counting?

Comment: You may just be keeping too much in memory. Do you ever release the images that you set on the image views (say, when the user scrolls them offscreen)?

Comment: Yes I'm using Automatic Reference Counting with xCode 4.6

Comment: Thanks Tim. It crashes when It's just reading the image data from the disk. For example, when I run the program once and everything is stored  on the disk. the second time that I run it and it's just reading from the disk after it loads some images to the imageview it crashes.

Comment: I edited my question and explained the situation more.

Comment: Have you run your app through instruments to see where you memory is going?  The UIImageViews that are displaying the images are they being reused / removed or are they hanging around in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're holding too many images in memory. When you open the second view, it's reloading the images again from disk, until you end up with two copies of all the images.

The UIImage class may be able to help you with this memory management. In its [reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it mentions that it has the capability to purge its data in low-memory situations and then reload the file from disk when it needs to be drawn again. This might be your solution.

However, as you're creating the image from an NSData read from disk, the UIImage will probably not be able to purge its memory - it won't know that your image is simply stored on the disk, so it can't throw away the data and reload it later.

Try changing your "imageWith" method to create a UIImage (via imageWithContentsOfFile) from the file URL on the disk just before it returns, and return the UIImage rather than returning the intermediate NSData. That way, the UIImage will know where on disk its image source came from and be able to intelligently purge/reload it as memory becomes constrained on the device.

Comment: "It sounds like you're holding too many images in memory." you were right about this. so what I did was I changed the code so I had only 10 uiimages at the time. and there was no more memory warnings.

Comment: I also changed to imageWithContentsOfFile and returned UIimage instead of nsdata as you suggested. it didn't make any difference in case of memory warnings, but it just sounded more efficient, so that's what I did.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. you helped me a lot and I can't thank you enough :)